# Dynamic Flip Animation in windows phone 8 using C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a requirement that involves flipping of multiple grid cells in windows phone 8.

I am using a Grid layout as below.

```
-------------------------  
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+  
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+  
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+ 
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-------------------------
```

When i click on `| A |`in the first row, it flips horizontally and this comes up `| A' |`. Like wise i need to add flip animations for all the cells present above. Is there any easy way using C# that i can achieve this. Currently i am using the below way to do this.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <PointAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="0.5,0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="180"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="FlipCard" >
                <Storyboard >

                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="180"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="FlipCardBack" >
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="180"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>



// adding one more visual state group for another rectangle cell.


        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup1">
        <VisualState x:Name="FlipCard1" >
            <Storyboard >
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="180"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="FlipCardBack1" >
            <Storyboard >
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="180"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="aceSpades1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="cardBack1">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>  
          <!--   <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup2"> ......
             ....
             .....
             ...... (same repeats for other rectangle cell with different IDs)
        <   -->
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->


    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="aceSpades"  Fill="Tomato" Stretch="Fill" Tap="cardBack_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="cardBack" Fill="Tan" Stretch="Fill" Tap="cardBack_Tap">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle></Grid>


//adding another cell here


     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Rectangle x:Name="aceSpades1"  Fill="Aqua" Stretch="Fill" Tap="cardBack_Tap" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="cardBack1"  Fill="Brown" Stretch="Fill" Tap="cardBack_Tap">
            <Rectangle.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection/>
            </Rectangle.Projection>
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

  <!--  <Grid x:Name="ContentPane3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        ......
        ...... (untill how many cells we wish to have)
    </Grid>-->
</Grid>
```

But if i add up like that, i end up with huge lines and I am not sure if this is the way to add. I wanted to check if there is any way to add the same using c# code.

I can add the child Grid views manually though, but not sure how to add the Visualstatemanager objects using code and attach the same to the story board.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to study [Microsoft Reversy game sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712230.aspx). There is great VisualState samples that works mostly the same as you want. I have used them to build my own game that flips the cells too ;) This sample is for Windows Store app, but the VisualState styles works in Windows Phone without modifications.

Comment: I tried to use that source, but it says incompatible with my IDE Visual Express 2012 for Windows Phone. Can you suggest any option. I am new to c# development.

Also, how many cells were involved in your app that flips.

Comment: You can involve any amount of cells.  1. create grid, fill each cell with custom button with attached property. Listen for property changes  and change visual state to the corresponding visual state. Check the file BoardSpace.cs. So, flipping buttons is easy, like: `for(cnt;;cnt++){ button.state = newstate; }` All work is done in button class and visual states.